# Multi-site installation with shared database but different user table

Tags: 7, users, database, multi-sites

I need to install drupal multi-site with shared database but just need to create some tables specific to that site like, users table should be different for sub-sites.

I know about full sharing or full different database for different sites, but I need partial different database. I searched for it on google but didn't get exact solution so posting it here if anybody has clue about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try editing you sub-sites settings.php file and you just need to provide different prefix for user table (as you need only this table different).

I am providing sample here so that you can implement and see if it works.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => array(
           'users'     => 'abcsite_',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The above code will tell your installation to use `abcsite_users` (you need to create table first with same structure as of default users table) for entering user details.

Comment: I am able to share user fields.But how do I share user profile fields?